# How do I get the inner text of elements using the scraper crate?

Tags: web-scraping, rust

I am using the `scraper` library to parse an HTML document and find the node with ID `foo`.

I would like to use this node for further operations. For this example, I'm trying to reach some nested children with class `inner` and retrieve the `innerText` of those children.

```
use scraper::{Html, Selector};

fn main() {
    let html = String::from(
        r#"
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>Test</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <div id="foo"><div></div><div><div></div><div class="inner"><span>x<div>yo</div></span></div></div></div>
        </body>
      </html>
    "#,
    );

    let parsed_html = Html::parse_document(&html);
    let fragment = parsed_html
        .select(&Selector::parse("body").unwrap())
        .next()
        .unwrap();
    let foo = fragment
        .select(&Selector::parse("div#foo").unwrap())
        .next()
        .unwrap();

    let text = foo
        .children()
        .nth(1)
        .unwrap()
        .children()
        .nth(1)
        .unwrap()
        .children()
        .map(|child| child.value())
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    println!("{:?}", text);
}
```

my `Cargo.toml` file:

```
[package]
name = "scraper"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["foo@bar"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
scraper = "0.12.0"
```

The output of `rustup show`:

```
Default host: x86_64-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/foobar/.rustup

stable-x86_64-apple-darwin (directory override for '/Users/foobar')
rustc 1.43.1 (8d69840ab 2020-05-04)
```

The console prints out `[Element(<span>)]` which is the result of the mapping function where I call `value` method on element.

The outcome I'm expecting is `xyo`.

Does `scraper` crate have some methods that can extract the text like I want it to or would I have to create some kind of recursive function?

I know this code is prone to errors and I will use the `match` operator to handle cases where certain nodes aren't present in documents. For now I'm only focusing on how to get the `innerText` property on children nodes.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: I updated the question with example code. I'm unable to use Rust playground due to `scraper` dependency. I also rephrased my question little bit.

Comment: *I'm unable to use Rust playground* — that's fine, which is why my comment specifically addresses that possibility: **otherwise in a brand new Cargo project**. You still haven't provided all the info requested: *We can't tell what crates (**and their versions**)*

Comment: Added Cargo file that specifies the versoin of `scraper` crate and language edition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`scraper` has a method to extract the text: [`ElementRef::text`](https://docs.rs/scraper/0.12.0/scraper/element_ref/struct.ElementRef.html#method.text).

A way to achieve what you're looking for from the `.children()` calls would be:

```rust
...
.children()
.filter_map(|child| ElementRef::wrap(child))
.flat_map(|el| el.text())
.collect::<Vec<_>>(); // Or `.collect::<String>()` if you want xyo concatenated
```

However, given your example, I feel you may want to use a selector to directly get the `ElementRef` that corresponds to your target instead of doing the work with lots of `.children()`s:

```rust
let inner: String = parsed_html
    .select(&Selector::parse("body div#foo:nth-child(1):nth-child(1)").unwrap()) // or "body div#foo div.inner"
    .flat_map(|el| el.text())
    .collect();
```

This would look closer to [what is in the `scraper` documentation](https://docs.rs/scraper/0.12.0/scraper/index.html#accessing-descendent-text).

Comment: I completely missed that `ElementRef::wrap` in the documentation. Now it makes more sense. Thank you.